# Какой теоретически самый маленький пинг от Киева до Москвы?

Tags: ping

И, если можно, алгоритм, как вы это вычислили.

Comment: Прямое оптоволокно (совсем прямое, без всяких маршрутизаторов, ретрансляторов и прочего оборудования) 756 км / 300 000 км/с = 0,0025 c

Маловато чет правда выходит. Но у меня из Питера president.gov.ua за 30 мс отвечает.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Расстояние от Киева до Москвы порядка 850 км (это по дороге, но она близка к прямой). Сигналу нужно побежать туда и назад, бежать быстрее скорости света он не может. Поэтому

```
850 * 2 / 300000 = 5.6 мс
```

Это если не считать никаких накладных расходов. Только чистое время сигнала в пути.

**P.S.**

Перемерял точнее расстояние - там 750 км, если уж совсем по прямой. Это 5мс.

Comment: Обязательная ссылка на программистский фольклор по теме: <http://rauf.livejournal.com/23552.html> (оригинал: <http://www.ibiblio.org/harris/500milemail.html>).

Comment: А я думал провайдерам ещё есть куда стремится в этом плане, но многие и так уже подошли к порогу, получается). Конечно и 10-20 мс это уже хорошо даже для самых требовательных игр в плане реакции, хотя и говорят многие что 200мс у мозга предел, но по опыту скажу, что 10-20 мс очень сильно ощущается в некоторых играх. Можно ещё в клиент попробовать, наверное, вставить функцию, чтобы TCPNoDelay включал и TcpAckFrequency в 1 ставил. Тогда те, кто захотят, то смогут сократить пинг почти в два раза, не обращая внимания на возможные потери и ошибки? В тему http://www.gamedev.ru/flame/forum/?id=14845